# How to make a pivottable calculated field which must be shown for the corresponding row and column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to calculate a few numbers inside my pivottable, but unfortunately I am not able to make it work (not with what is in my head). I have a table containing my data, now the pivot needs to calculate values depending on particular columns.

I have tried multiple things, like making calculation fields for every year multiplying with each material, however I have 50+ materials and 10 years, so that would make the amount of combinations I have to make very large. I have a feeling that there is an easier option, but I haven't discovered how.

Here is a picture.

[image]

If possible I would like to make a max of 10 calculation fields where the material demand per country is given for different years.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I just don't know how I can any code or anything. It is not VBA, nor any formula, but just the Pivot-table function of Excel. I am looking for a way to set up the pivot table as I mention above.